# How access the member functions of a child class in another child class of same parent

Tags: php, oop

I've three classes lets say **Class A**, **Class B** and **Class C**.

Class A is parent class and class B and C are its child.

There is function in class B, I want to access that function in class C without inheriting Class C with B. Is it possible?

```
public class A {


}

class B extends A{

      public function hello (){
        return "Hello world";
      }
}

public class C extends A{

    public function world (){
        $this->hello();
    } 

}
```

Comment: It is not possible. Class `C` knows __nothing__ about what other classes are children of `A`. So you either `extends B` or move function from `B` to `A`.

Comment: You can force implementation of that method by using `abstract public function` in your base class. This however requires the base class to be `abstract` too.

Comment: You could pass in an object of type Class C as an argument to a method in Class B

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon @u_mulder's comment: it's indeed not possible, because though B and C both derive from the same class A, they are distinct classes, in the same way that a bicycle and a car are both vehicles. When using a bicycle you cannot assume to use functions from a car, simply because they're both vehicles.

The question you'd need to answer yourself is what is the functionality of the method I need in `class B`? Is it specific to `class B`? Or is it something all entities which are `class A`? Or different yet, is it a separately functionality altogether but which only `class B` needs to consume?
The solution to the first case would be to move the function to `class B`. In the second case you'd move the function to class A. In the third case you'd implement the function in a separate class and inject that into `class B`.

I recommend you read up on [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles and [other principles of OOP](https://dzone.com/articles/solid-grasp-and-other-basic-principles-of-object-o) design